# Grails dependency error when running app on Ubuntu

Tags: grails, ubuntu

I'm running into the following problem when trying to run an app wiht grails 2.0.3 on Ubuntu (8) which runs fine on OSX:

```
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: org.grails.plugins#resources;1.1.6: configuration not found in org.grails.plugins#resources;1.1.6: 'master'. It was required from org.grails.plugins#jquery-mobile;1.0.3 compile
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    :: org.grails.plugins#resources;1.1.6: configuration not found in org.grails.plugins#resources;1.1.6: 'master'. It was required from org.grails.plugins#jquery-mobile;1.0.3 compile
    ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:resources:latest.integration
```

Any idea where to look for the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is maybe a problem with the load order of the plugins.

When running into similar problems I removed all plugins from application.properties and added plugin after plugin (restarting each time the server).

Comment: Solved my own problem which was created by upgrading form grails 2.0.1 to 2.0.3:
I had to manually change the resources plugin version from 1.1.5 to 1.1.6 in BuildConfig. Don't know why this didn't happen automatically on upgradinging the project. I'm not allowed to answer my own question though during the first 8 hrs. :-/

Answer (score 1):

all the plugins and project information is saved off in two directories

.grails

and

.ivy2

Normally they are under you user home account.

When upgrading you should you the grails upgrade command. This will resolve all of your plugin information.

If you are having problems the other thing you can do is delete your .grails and .ivy2 dirs and rebuild your project from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, which is why I found this question.  I got it working just by running the run-app command again.